# Error array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

Tags: c++, arrays

What am I doing wrong in this?
Error array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

```
   using namespace std;

bool cars_present[20];
int count = 0;
void sortArrayIntegers(int IDs[count]);

struct date
{
   int day, month, year;
};

struct car
{
   int ID;
   char owner_name[20], owner_surname[20], make[20], model[20], phone_number[10];
   struct date reg_date, ns_date;
}car_directory[100];
```

Comment: Well, `count` is not a constant, compiler is right. Just use `std::array` or `std::vector`. Or make `count` `constexpr`. Also arrays with size 0 are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void sortArrayIntegers(int IDs[count]);
```

Please try changing this line to

void sortArrayIntegers(int IDs[]);

You dont need to provide a value here

Comment: Arrays of length 0 are not valid.

Comment: Yeah, Modified the answer. In the method declaration, you don't need to provide a length

Comment: `IDs` is just a pointer then. You don't have to provide a length in the definition either. One more argument favoring `std::array`, if you have an actual, fixed size or `std::vector` when it's dynamic.

Comment: How would you implement this function? If you pass an array of integers by `int IDs[]`, you won't be able to do anything useful with it because you don't know it's size.